# What is the best way to level transmutation in Everquest 2 if you got a late start

Tags: everquest-2

I've been playing EverQuest 2 Extended with my after quitting WoW several months ago.  Not used to the tradeskill system in EQ we didn't realize you started with the transmutation skill instead of having to learn it, so I didn't start transmuting anything until I hit level 15.  Unfortunately, by then I'd gotten rid of most of my low level gear.  Low level mobs won't drop me items since they're grey, and finding rare mats to craft Mastercrafted quality items takes forever and since the highest level item I can make of the first tier is level 2, they rarely give skillups.  Is there a better way to do this? We're on bronze accounts so we can't use the broker or anything, and my limited bank slots are filling up with gear that I could disenchant if I could just get to X or Y or Z level transmutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a way that is at least, not as painful, though it's still not super fast.  The scholar type crafting professions (sage, artificing, and alchemy) can create skill learning items for various classes.  Skill items of at least expert level can be transmuted like Treasured or Mastercrafted items.  Unlike Mastercrafted items, these items can have levels other than X1 and X2.  This seems to be the only way to craft transmutable items high enough level to give a decent chance at skillups. 
There's also a mount you can get from a crafting quest chain in Butcherblock Mountains that increases your transmutation skill by 9.

Answer (score 2):

You can also visit a chronomage in one of the main cities and self-mentor back to a lower level, such as 5 or 10. You can then get transmutable drops again. I can't remember for sure if that option is available at any level or not until level 20, but if self-mentoring doesn't work you could have your friend create a new character for you to mentor down to.